# OpenCV C++ Resize issues

Tags: c++, opencv, image-resizing

I'm trying to use the `resize` function in OpenCV in c++ but the images are not changed. Both images are loaded but whatever I set the `fx, fy` makes no difference. How can I solve it?

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"   
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    Mat OriginalImage = imread("cornrow1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Mat ModifiedImage = imread("cornrow1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    void resize(InputArray OriginalImage, OutputArray ModifiedImage, Size (*), double fx = .2, double fy = .2, int = INTER_LANCZOS4);
    imshow("color", ModifiedImage);
    imshow("color2", OriginalImage);
}
```

Note that I have modified the line below to the second line but that gives me an "unhandled exception at memory location..."

```
Mat ModifiedImage = imread("cornrow1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
Mat ModifiedImage;
```

Comment: try cv::resize(OriginalImage, ModifiedImage, cv::Size(), 0.2,0.2);

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I also went ahead and edited my code and took a look at the Toby Speight article.

Answer (score 0):

`void resize(...)` in your code is a function declaration, not function call. I guess you want something like this instead:

```
resize(OriginalImage, ModifiedImage, ModifiedImage.size());
```

Comment: in general you are right, but instead of third parameter ModifiedImage.size() he has to set a target size or cv::Size() and fourth + fifth parameters the ne relative dimension sizes.